# R: Extract/mark the first existing date and last which is largest date among 20th-22nd per each month, out of a list of dates over years

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe in R, where each row includes a date in the first column. There can be many rows i.e. dates for several years.
I would like to find/mark the first day per each new month, and the 3rd trading day before the 25th per each month and if it doesn't exist then choose the day before.
For example, in the following aux_sim, it would be the first row (1942), row 1953, and 1960

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
aux_sim$date <- as.Date(aux_sim$date, "%d/%m/%Y")

# create columns day, month, year
aux_sim <- aux_sim %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(d= day(date), m=month(date), y=year(date))

# extract first row of each month, year
a <- aux_sim %>%
  group_by(m, y) %>% 
  slice(1)

# extract the last-2 row of each month, year with day<=25
b <- aux_sim %>% 
  group_by(m, y) %>% 
  filter(d<=25) %>% 
  slice(n()-2)

rbind(a, b) %>% arrange(date) %>% select(date, spot.price.Crude.oil)
```

Answer (score 0):

To simulate your data I have made a DF consisting out of all days in *2000* and some simulated data between `25` and `35`. I have removed Feb 25th, in order to check on one of your subtasks.

With `lubridate` the date is split into days, months and year and the DF is nested with `month`. With `purrr::map_lgl` it is checked, if the months contains 25 and with that boolean the (temporary) variable `check` got either 22 for 21 which would be the last trading days before 25 - according to your task.
A new variable `mark` was created which cecked for the last trading day, which was then marked with an `X`. After this the first trading day of the month was marked with an `Y`.

At the end the temporary variables are deleted.

The output at the end does not show the complete DF but only those data which had a mark of either `X` or `Y`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

d <- seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), as.Date('2000-12-31'), by = 'days')

# simulate sone values between 25 and 35
set.seed(1)
n <- round(runif(length(d) ,0.25,.35), 4)*100


# remove Feb 25
df <- data.frame(d,n)
df <- df %>% filter(d != as.Date('2000-02-25'))

new_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(day = day(d),
         month = month(d),
         year = year(d)
         ) %>%
  group_by(month) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(has_25 = map_lgl(data, ~{25 %in% .x$day}, data = .x)) %>% 
  mutate(check = ifelse(has_25, 22, 21)) %>% 
  unnest(cols = data) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(mark = ifelse((day == 22 & check == 22) |
                        (day == 21 & check == 21), 'X', '')) %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  mutate(mark = ifelse(day == min(day), 'Y', mark)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(d, n, mark)

# just to show which data are maked with either 'Y' (first day in month) 
# or with 'X' (last trading day before 25th)

new_df %>% filter(mark != '')
#> # A tibble: 24 x 4
#> # Groups:   month [12]
#>    month d              n mark 
#>    <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <chr>
#>  1     1 2000-01-01  27.7 Y    
#>  2     1 2000-01-22  27.1 X    
#>  3     2 2000-02-01  31   Y    
#>  4     2 2000-02-21  33.6 X    
#>  5     3 2000-03-01  34.1 Y    
#>  6     3 2000-03-22  32.1 X    
#>  7     4 2000-04-01  25.6 Y    
#>  8     4 2000-04-22  28.6 X    
#>  9     5 2000-05-01  30.0 Y    
#> 10     5 2000-05-22  27.4 X    
#> # … with 14 more rows
```